# Multipart form data throwing error in express js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multipartform-data, content-type

I have a express proxy server for angular application. From angular I am making post request to expressjs, there the same formData posting to backend and getting 500 as response.

```
 app.post('/upload', upload.any(), (request, response) => {
    const formData = new FormData({'file': request.file});
    axios.post(loaderUrl + `/loads`, formData, {headers:formData.getHeaders()})
        .then(resp => {
            response.send(resp.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            response.send(error);
        });
});

Here request.file = {
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'Sample.xlsx',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  buffer: <Buffer 50 6d 6c 20 ... 46844 more bytes>,
  size: 46894
}

Backend error log: "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the content-type header.

```
headers: {
Content-Type: multipart/form-data,
formData.getHeaders()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Backend error log: "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request"
```

The error above clearly states that the request you are sending to the server is not of the exact type that is required. The request should explicitly state its type i.e. Multipart.

You can achieve that by replacing this line of code

```
axios.post(loaderUrl + `/loads`, formData, {headers:formData.getHeaders()})
```

With

```
axios.post(loaderUrl + `/loads`, formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```